# Why is the eventListener not being applied to the button element?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Currently developing a shop-like web page for a school task and I am running into a problem where the eventListeners seem to not be applied to the button elements.

I'm running a `forEach` loop on an array containing data on the items that you can buy in the shop. Basically, every `object` in `array` > print article with object data to the container, along with adding an eventListener to the button which is supposed to pass along data to a handleBuyEvent function to further check if the user has enough money/resources etc. etc.

The issue is when the articles are printed to the web page (no errors in the console) nothing happens when I click the buttons, and when I inspect the button elements, under eventListeners it says no listeners...

```js
import WarriorsModule from "./modules/warriorsModule.js";
import InventoryModule from "./modules/inventoryModule.js";
const warriors = WarriorsModule().getAll(); // returns array with objects containing data
const inventory = InventoryModule();

const warriorsContainer = document.querySelector("#warriorsContainer");
const ironResources = document.querySelector("#ironResource");
const coinResources = document.querySelector("#coinResource");
const woodResources = document.querySelector("#woodResource");

// Updates current resources on screen.
const updateResources = () => {
  ironResources.innerHTML = inventory.getIronBalance();
  coinResources.innerHTML = inventory.getCoinBalance();
  woodResources.innerHTML = inventory.getWoodBalance();
}

updateResources();

const handleBuyEvent = (category, price, img) => {

  if (inventory.getCoinBalance() >= price) {

    inventory.addToArmy({
        category: `${category}`,
        price: `${price}`,
        img: `${img}`
    });

    inventory.removeCoins(price);
    updateResources();

  } else {

    alert(
      `You are missing: ${
          (price - inventory.getCoinBalance())
      } coins to buy this unit.`
    );

  }

};

let handleClickEvent = (category, price, img) => {
  handleBuyEvent(category, price, img);
};

const printWarriors = () => {

  // This id is being used to identify the different buttons and containers in each article
  let id = 0;

  warriors.forEach((object) => {

    const buttonContainer = document.createElement("div");

    buttonContainer.setAttribute("id", `buttonContainer${id}`);

    // Create the button element and set up its properties
    const buttonElement = document.createElement("button");

    buttonElement.setAttribute("id", `buyButton${id}`);
    buttonElement.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success m-4");
    buttonElement.innerHTML = `
      Buy ${object.category} Warrior - ${object.price}
    `;

    const category = object.category;
    const price = object.price;
    const img = object.img;

    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      handleClickEvent(category, price, img);
    });

    buttonContainer.appendChild(buttonElement);

    // Prints article to website
    warriorsContainer.innerHTML += `
      <article class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="warriorArticle shadow rounded d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
          <h3 class="m-4 fs-2" >${object.category}</h3>
          <div class="row">
              <img class="categoryImage" src="${object.img}" alt="${object.category}-img"/>
          </div>
          ${buttonContainer.outerHTML}
        </div>
      </article>
    `;
    
    // Increments the ID so that on the next iteration the ID set is different.
    id += 1;

  });
};

printWarriors();
```

I have tried asking chatGPT 100 times but it doesn't seem to find the issue. I read through the code to see if there was a mistake somewhere regarding getting the ID for certain elements in case that is why it was never applied.

At this point, I have no idea why it won't work and at the same time gives no errors AND everything else is printed and shown as expected.

Comment: Once you've converted `buttonContainer` to a string that string no longer has any relationship with the element. Therefore any event listener it had is gone. Instead do `warriorArticleDiv.appendChild(buttonContainer)`

Comment: adding `buttonContainer.outerHTML` to `warriorsContainer.innerHTML` creates new elements, so the listeners added by `addEventListener` are not included

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue arises from the order in which you are executing operations. When you create the `buttonElement` and attach an event listener to it, the element exists in memory but has not been attached to the `DOM` yet. However, when you later append the entire `article` to `warriorsContainer` using `innerHTML`, it **does not** copy the event listeners.

Here's a breakdown of my understanding of the task:

1. Create the `buttonElement` and attach an event listener to it.
2. Append this buttonElement to the `buttonContainer`.
3. Append this `buttonContainer` to the warriorsContainer using innerHTML +=.

That said, using `innerHTML +=` does not copy over the event listeners from the in-memory version of the element. To resolve this, you need to attach the created DOM nodes directly to the warriorsContainer without converting them to strings with innerHTML.

Here's a revised version of the `printWarriors` function to fix this:

```js
const printWarriors = () => {
  let id = 0;

  warriors.forEach((object) => {
    const warriorArticle = document.createElement("div");
    warriorArticle.className = "warriorArticle shadow rounded d-flex flex-column align-items-center";

    const header = document.createElement("h3");
    header.className = "m-4 fs-2";
    header.textContent = object.category;

    const imgDiv = document.createElement("div");
    imgDiv.className = "row";
    const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
    imgElement.className = "categoryImage";
    imgElement.src = object.img;
    imgElement.alt = `${object.category}-img`;
    imgDiv.appendChild(imgElement);

    const buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
    buttonElement.id = `buyButton${id}`;
    buttonElement.className = "btn btn-success m-4";
    buttonElement.textContent = `Buy ${object.category} Warrior - ${object.price}`;
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      handleClickEvent(object.category, object.price, object.img);
    });

    warriorArticle.appendChild(header);
    warriorArticle.appendChild(imgDiv);
    warriorArticle.appendChild(buttonElement);

    const article = document.createElement("article");
    article.className = "col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4";
    article.appendChild(warriorArticle);

    warriorsContainer.appendChild(article);
    id += 1;
  });
};
```

By using the `DOM` methods `(createElement, appendChild, etc.)` and not using `innerHTML` for appending dynamic content, the event listeners attached to elements remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you added `buttonContainer` using `warriorsContainer.innerHTML` and `buttonContainer.outerHTML`. If you want to add the actual button along with its event listeners to the DOM, you need to truly insert the element using something like `appendChild()` or `insertAdjacentElement()`.